# Disabling Swipe at first view and last view in uipageviewcontroller

Tags: ios, uipageviewcontroller

I am using a `PageViewController`. I want to disable the swipe when the page is either the first or last.

If first page is displayed then left swipe should be disabled and when the page is in last then right swipe gesture to be disabled.

If I use the following code then the swipe is not working

```
if(index == 0)
  for (UIScrollView *view in pageViewController.view.subviews) {

        if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]]) {

            view.scrollEnabled = NO;
        }
    }  }
  else if(index ==[images_array count]){
   for (UIScrollView *view in pageViewController.view.subviews) {

        if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]]) {

            view.scrollEnabled = NO;
        }
    } }
```

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the following method which will be called when you scroll to a view controller. You can then check to see if it's at the right index and then disable scrolling.

```
func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, willTransitionToViewControllers pendingViewControllers: [UIViewController]) {
    if pendingViewControllers.count > 0 {
        let vc = pendingViewControllers[0] as! ViewController
        // Check index of vc


    }
}
```

And in Objective-C:

```
- (void)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController
willTransitionToViewControllers:(NSArray<UIViewController *> *)pendingViewControllers {
    if ([pendingViewControllers count] > 0) {
        ViewController *vc = pendingViewControllers[0]
        // Check index of vc


    }
}
```